# How Can I Create Custom Auth For Firebase (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to add users to Firebase with usernames,p passwords, and emails. I'm using the Email-Password sign-in method but how can I add the username to the database?
Here is the basic code that I wrote for the email&password sign-in method:

```
    fun signup(view:View){
        val email = binding.emailText.text.toString()
        val username = binding.usernameText2.text.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordText2.text.toString()
        if(email.equals("") || username.equals("") || password.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Don't Leave them empty!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnSuccessListener {
                //sucess
                val intent = Intent(this@SignupActivity,FeedsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                //failed
                Toast.makeText(this,it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend checking out some of these top answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-authentication%5d%5bandroid%5d%20add%20username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add some data to the database, you have to choose which database you want to use. You can use either [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). Now, since the sign-in operation is asynchronous, the code that writes data to the database should be added inside the callback. That being said, get the data from the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object:

```
val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val email = firebaseUser?.email
val displayName = firebaseUser?.displayName
val user = mapOf(
    displayName to displayName,
    email to email
)
```

And add it to Firestore:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = db.collection("users")
usersRef.document(uid).set(user)
```

Or in the Realtime Database:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = db.child("users")
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(user)
```